# What are the irreducible components of $V(xy,xz,yz)\subset\Bbb A^3$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = V (xy, xz, yz)$ in $\Bbb A^3$
How can I write $X$ as a union of irreducible components and describe the intersection of the irreducible components?

I know that we can take the equations determining an algebraic set $V(I)$, and one of them factors so that $V(I)$ decomposes as $V(J_1)\cup V(J_2)\cup\cdots$

I tried the decomposition

[image]

I need help with writing $X$ as union of irreducible components and describing the intersection.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The points of that variety are fairly easy to describe algebraically, and perhaps more difficult is visualizing them in 3d. Since you require that all $xy=xz=yz=0$, if any two of our three variables equal $0$, then that point is in V. Try to think about what this would be geometrically.

Comment: I think if any two of the three variables are zero then it represents axis in 3d

Comment: Now you should be able to finish it off :).